# This one has everything covered

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, steganography

> Long, hard work days are required in the job, but it won't make Orlov quit. One quickly sees he's overqualified. Kites, brown bears, very quiet quails, even red foxes love the quaint zookeeper. A frog jumps tranquilly off his hand-knit quilt. The open lunch box has fresh quinoa and verdant squash. There's a sly quality in the joyful quirks of this swell quaker. He lays down a plaque which says "bbq night". Email quiets down here. Quacks, moos, roars and dog barks continue. Such a peaceful life.

The answer is a well-known phrase.

Comment: It seems, it is to do with - covering entire alphabets ( a through z)...in sentences. Such as -  _A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog_ , I guess.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay That would definitely fit the title!

Comment: @Deusovi: Doesn't the new tag contradict "enigmatic puzzle"? I think in this case that tag is a spoiler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is ...

> ... the well-known pangram **The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog**. It is hidden in the text.

How?

> There are suspiciously many q's in the text. If we take the letters before each q, they spell:
>
>  **Every tenth syllable**.
>
>  So let's look at every tenth syllable:
>
>  Long, hard work days are re·qui·red in **the**
>  job, but it won't make Or·lov quit. One **quick**·
>  ly sees he's o·ver·qua·li·fied. Kites, **brown**
>  bears, very quiet quails, even red **fox**·
>  es love the quaint zoo·kee·per. A frog **jumps**
>  tran·quil·ly off his hand-knit quilt. The **o**·
>  pen lunch box has fresh qui·no·a and **ver**·
>  dant squash. There's a sly qua·li·ty in **the**
>  joy·ful quirks of this swell qua·ker. He **lays**
>  down a plaque which says "b·b·q night". **E**·
>  mail quiets down here. Quacks, moos, roars and **dog**
>  barks con·ti·nue. Such a peaceful life.
>
>  Voilà! Funny how the single z in the text isn't used to spell "lazy".

Comment: i got all the way there, but i put rot13(abg rabhtu flyynoyrf va er-dhverq).  nice job!

Comment: Also if you look at rot13(gur pncvgny yrggref, vg fcryyf "YBBX NG GUR DF")

Comment: @SteveV: Well spotted, I missed the acrostic and just found the letter distribution curious. And I have to admit that I had an idea where this was going and made the syllables fit. (I'm never quite sure what constitutes a syllable in English, let alone where to hyphenate words.)

Comment: isn't this simply copying from the comment that was posted 3 hours before your answer? this count as your own answer? or the guy who commented it first? or should you mark this as community?

Comment: @NaeemShaikh: No. I've outlined how the phrase is hidden in the text (well, except that I missed the first step, which I guessed). Mea Cupla Nay just put out a guess, probably based on the title and the fact that the texdt is a pangram. If they wanted to post an answer, they could have done so, but it would probably have elicited comments asking to explain te answer. Everything you post here is in public domain and others can make use of it.

Comment: Nice work. You didn't even need the first clue I threw in there to get people on the right track.